# SQL- How to grab a large list of data instead of iterating each query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I gather a list of items for each item I check the database with SQL query with the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM task_activity as ja 
join task as j on ja.task_id = j.id 
WHERE j.name = '%s' 
  AND ja.avg_runtime <> 0 
  AND ja.avg_runtime is not NULL 
  AND ja.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM task_activity 
               WHERE task_id = ja.task_id 
                 and avg_runtime <> 0 
                 AND ja.avg_runtime is not NULL) 
  % str(task.get('name'))).fetchall()
```

But do I need to iterate through the list and make a query for everyone. This list is quite large at times. Can I just make one query and get back a list data set?
In this particular query I'm only looking for the column avg_runtime with the task id and the maximum id will be the last calculated runtime.

I don't have access to the database other then to make queries. Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3349.0 (X64)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to speed this up using `row_number()`. Note, I think there's a bug in your original query. Should `ja.avg_runtime` in the subquery just be `avg_runtime`?

```py
sql = """with x as (
    select
        task_id,
        avg_runtime,
        id,
        row_number() over (partition by ja.task_id order by ja.id desc) rn
    from
        task_activity as ja 
            join 
        task as j 
            on ja.task_id = j.id 
    where
        j.name in ({0}) and
        ja.avg_runtime <> 0 and
        ja.avg_runtime is not null        
) select
    task_id,
    avg_runtime,
    id
from
    x
where
    rn = 1;"""

# build up ?,?,? for parameter substitution
# assume tasknames is the list containing the task names.
params = ",".join(tasknames.map(lambda x: "?"))
# connection is your db connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
# interpolate the ?,?,? and bind parameters
cursor.execute(sql.format(params), tasknames)
cursor.fetchall()
```

the following index should make this query pretty fast (although it depends how many rows are being excluded by the filters on `ja.avg_runtime`):

```
create index ix_task_id_id on task_activity (task_id, id desc);
```

Comment: Will you see edit does that affect anything? Basically I input the name of the task with the formatter.

Comment: @user3590149 You need to build SQL with `j.name in ('%s', '%s2', ...)`. I'm not sure what language you're using to build this up. It looks somewhat prone to SQL injection as things stand.

Comment: @user3590149 I've not used Python much, but I've put something in to build up some parameters for substitution and then executing them. You'll have to fill in some gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: What database library are you using? I've assumed ODBC (pyodbc) in this example.

Comment: I can't test this until tomorrow. How does the 'create index work'? This another query?

Comment: SQLAlchemy is what I'm using if that changes anything.

Comment: if name was equal TESTNAME, can show me how to make the query just alone from the rest? Just as a with query. What does the ({0}) mean?

Comment: {0} is read by the format function. It substitutes a string in in it's place. e.g. `"Hello {0}".format("Loz")` would return `"Hello Loz"`. I'm using this because you need to bind one parameter for each name in the list. so it ends up with "name in (?,?,?,?) with one question mark for each parameter. Then cursor.execute can take a list of parameters and substitute the values for the question marks. This also takes care of SQL Injection problems. SQLAlchemy sits on top of a DBAPI implementation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mssql.html Do you know which you are using?

Comment: It comes up with mssql ODBC. I believe that's pyodbc. I'm getting a problem saying that I can't send only a maximum of 2100, do you have suggestion to deal with this.

Comment: Ultimately in your query the second value is the only value I need but if there is no entry or if the entry is blank then I need to disregard. Is this possible?

Comment: DO you have more than 2100 task names in your list? If so, you'll need to process in batches of less than that.

Comment: Yes I do. Going to have to do some research on how to do that? Any suggestions.

Comment: You need to cut your list into sublists of less than 2000, then call a procedure to do the database bit on each sublist. If the list of tasks is already stored on the database somewhere, you may be able to adapt the query to use it instead.